# Accessing resources in fragment background task returns illegalStateException often

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making an asynchronous network request to fetch reviews and trailers.

If the reviews and trailers are present then they are set as TextView texts. If there are no reviews present then I am setting the textview test as **"No reviews"(message_no_reviews)** which is a predefined string variable in `strings.xml` file.

Now in order to display that text when no reviews are available I am fetching that using

```
getResources().getString(R.string.message_no_reviews)
```

The problem is that call to `getResources().getString(R.string.message_no_reviews)` returns `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MovieDetailFragment{1fdfd76} not attached to Activity` many times whereas call to `getResources().getString(R.string.api_key)` does not cause any Exception.

Following is the code snippet.

```
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getReviews();
        getTrailers();
    } 

public void getReviews(){


    Call<JsonObject> getReviewsCall = apiService.getReview(movie.getId(),getResources().getString(R.string.api_key));


    getReviewsCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<JsonObject> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            if (response.body() != null) {

                JsonArray reviews=(JsonArray) response.body().get("results");
                System.out.println(reviews);
                if(reviews.size()>0) {
                    tvReviewText.setText(((JsonObject) reviews.get(0)).get("content").getAsString());
                    tvReviewAuthor.setText(((JsonObject) reviews.get(0)).get("author").getAsString());

                }
                else{

                    tvReviewAuthor.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.message_no_reviews));
                    tvReviewText.setText("");
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }

    });


}
```

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

below is the logcat

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.vipin.www.popularmovies, PID: 21580
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MovieDetailFragment{1fdfd76} not attached to Activity
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:636)
     at com.vipin.www.popularmovies.MovieDetailFragment$2.onResponse(MovieDetailFragment.java:168)
     at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallback$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:86)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: put your logcat also ..............

Comment: Place any code the needs an Activity inside or after the onAttach method of a Fragment, that should fix at least one of the mentioned errors

Comment: @cricket_007 That is hardly any problem. As you can see there are 2 calls to getResources(). getResources().getString(R.string.api_key) works fine but getResources().getString(R.string.message_no_reviews) throws excetion

Comment: @cricket_007 but that would throw an Exception if your Fragment is not inflated

Comment: You do know you could just do `tvReviewAuthor.setText(R.string.message_no_reviews);` right? Please try that.

Comment: when do you call the get review?

Answer (score 5):

Your fragment is not attached to activity means:your fragment is not visible to user at that time since you made a network call from a button it create a another background thread and then you either backStack fragment or remove it from activity . So when response comes to onResponse method its context not available.

So You should use:

```
Fragment.this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_no_reviews));
```

or create a boolean whether fragment is attached or not in onCreate() and onDestroy()

Comment: this should be marked as the answer! thank you saved me a headache!

Comment: When I'm doing this,  it gives android.support.V4.app.Fragment is not an enclosing class.

Comment: @Mansuu.... it's because you are using android.support.V4.app.Fragment. You should use your fragment class where you use the code.

Answer (score 1):

`tvReviewAuthor.setText(getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.message_no_reviews));`
This should do the work You need Context Object to access String Resources

Comment: I tried using that but getActivity() return null in such case most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use **onAttach()** method to know when your fragment is attached to activity and also get context in it and use it to call other methods like this

```
    @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    activity = context;
}
```

and then you can do this

```
tvReviewAuthor.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.message_no_reviews));
```

Comment: how is this even different

Comment: also your creatting a space for memory leaks that is the Activity object won't be destroyed till the Fragment Object is not destroyed

Comment: in this context is received in onAttach() method which is probably error that fragment not attached

Comment: @vipinagrahari sorry I missed one part in answer instead of getActivity() use context . I have also updated in answer